# VSCode-Remote Tunnels Server Install Path

Tags: vscode-remote, vscode-remote-ssh

I'm using the vscode remote tunnels, which I believe are a relatively new feature. When I follow the instructions [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/tunnels), and connect to the tunnel, the `.vscode-server` directory gets installed in the root directory on the remote machine, but I would like it to be installed in a specific directory- ideally with a setting similar to the `remote.SSH.serverInstallPath`.

I know there is the cli option `--cli-data-dir` for the `code tunnel` command, but despite specifying this and the `remote.SSH.serverInstallPath` for the corresponding host it still installs in the root directory. I'm not sure if I'm missing some setting or if this just isn't available yet.

Comment: I was playing with this today and `--cli-data-dir` moves the contents normally in ~/.vscode-cli into <cli_data_dir>. I also set remote.SSH.serverInstallPath but it didn't do anything for me as far as moving .vscode-server. Did you figure this out?

Comment: No I didn't, I actually ended up going with a workflow using a third party [wrapper](https://github.com/coder/code-server) that essentially spins vscode up as a server so you can create a tunnel with vscode very similarly to how you might with jupyter notebook. This was the easiest way I found for development on the compute nodes of our 2FA HPCs. If you're interested, this [blog post](https://isaiahtaylor.medium.com/use-vs-code-on-a-supercomputer-15e4cbbb1bc2) has some details. The native vscode tunnel approach may be better in future once it has had more development/documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came across this issue when I was trying to make the VS Code Tunnel use the same VS Code server as VS Code Remote - SSH uses.

I ended up writing the following shell script wrapper to invoke `code tunnel`:

```bash
#!/bin/sh -e

export VSCODE_AGENT_FOLDER='<serverInstallPath>/.vscode-server'  # (1)
export VSCODE_CLI_DATA_DIR="$VSCODE_AGENT_FOLDER/cli"            # (2)
exec code tunnel "$@"
```

Footnotes:

1. This points my user data and extensions for the VS Code Tunnel server to the same user data and extensions used by the VS Code Remote - SSH server. Of course, replace `<serverInstallPath>` with the actual path you specified in `remote.SSH.serverInstallPath`.
2. This points the CLI data directory to the `<serverInstallPath>/.vscode-server/cli`, which appears to be created as an empty subdirectory of `<serverInstallPath>/.vscode-server` when using VS Code Remote - SSH.

This solution allows the VS Code Remote - SSH and VS Code Tunnel servers to share the same user data and extensions. However, the actual paths for the VS Code server installations themselves will differ (e.g., `<serverInstallPath>/.vscode-server/cli/servers/Stable-1a5daa3a0231a0fbba4f14db7ec463cf99d7768e/server` for VS Code Tunnel vs. `<serverInstallPath>/.vscode-server/bin/1a5daa3a0231a0fbba4f14db7ec463cf99d7768e` for VS Code Remote - SSH). I don't think this should cause any issues.

## Explanation

Both the VS Code Remote - SSH and the VS Code Tunnel features are using the same underlying feature, the VS Code server.

When you use VS Code Remote - SSH, you can specify a path using the `remote.SSH.serverInstallPath` setting on the VS Code client, which defaults to `~`. Then:

- The **VS Code server itself** (including the `code` executable, libraries, etc.) is installed within `<serverInstallPath>/.vscode-server/bin`, e.g., `~/.vscode-server/bin/1a5daa3a0231a0fbba4f14db7ec463cf99d7768e`.
- The **user data and extensions** are stored within the `<serverInstallPath>/.vscode-server/data` and `<serverInstallPath>/.vscode-server/extensions`, respectively, i.e., `~/.vscode-server/data` and `~/.vscode-server/extensions` by default.

  - The way this happens under the hood is as follows: when `remote.SSH.serverInstallPath` is set, the VS Code Remote - SSH extension sets the environment variable `VSCODE_AGENT_FOLDER` to `<serverInstallPath>/.vscode-server` within the SSH session before starting the VS Code server. This environment variable is read by [vs/server/node/server.main.ts](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/92772dcc29bd74108ab61ba9da5ad1f5154639ff/src/vs/server/node/server.main.ts#L39C55-L39C89) to determine the `--user-data-dir` and `--extensions-dir` arguments for the VS Code server.

For VS Code Remote - SSH, these locations are all controlled by the one setting `remote.SSH.serverInstallPath`.

For the VS Code Tunnel, these locations are controlled in two different ways.

- The **VS Code server itself** is installed within `<CLI data directory>/servers`, e.g., `~/.vscode/cli/servers/Stable-1a5daa3a0231a0fbba4f14db7ec463cf99d7768e/server`.

  - The CLI data directory defaults to `~/.vscode/cli`, but it can be set by the `--cli-data-dir` command-line argument to `code tunnel` or by the `VSCODE_CLI_DATA_DIR` environment variable.
- The **user data and extensions** are stored at `~/.vscode-server/data` and `~/.vscode-server/extensions` by default, and there is no explicitly documented way to change this.

  - However, since the VS Code server used for VS Code Tunnels uses the same underlying server feature as VS Code Remote - SSH, you can do the same thing VS Code Remote - SSH does and set the environment variable `VSCODE_AGENT_FOLDER` to your desired location, resulting in the paths `$VSCODE_AGENT_FOLDER/data` and `$VSCODE_AGENT_FOLDER/extensions` for the user data and extensions, respectively.

Answer (score 1):

Works with `code --user-data-dir=/home/code/ tunnel`. The `=` is important, otherwise it will be misinterpreted.

Comment: This unfortunately didn't work for me. Despite specifying a custom `--user-data-dir`, my user data and extensions were still being stored at `~/.vscode-server`.